# aligning ggplot faceted raster maps with a single map (separate legends)

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster

I would like to grid arrange 2 grobs, one is a faceted ggplot of `geom_raster` and the other is a single ggplot of `geom_raster`

the problem is they come out as very different sizes;

```
# make some dummy rasters
r1 <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=100,ymn=0,ymx=150,res=1)
r1[] <- sample(50:60,ncell(r1),replace = T)
r2 <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=100,ymn=0,ymx=150,res=1)
r2[] <- sample(50:60,ncell(r2),replace = T)

# delta (will be on a very different scale to the originals and i dont want that info dampened)
r3 <- r1-r2

# stack rasters and send to melted DT
st_1 <- stack(r1,r2)
names(st_1) <- c("raster_1","raster_2")
dt_st_1 <- as.data.frame(st_1, xy=T)
dt_st_1_m <- setDT(melt(dt_st_1, id.vars = c("x","y")))

# melt the delta raster
dt_diff <- as.data.frame(r3, xy=T)
dt_diff_m <- setDT(melt(dt_diff, id.vars = c("x","y")))

# plot one is the two data surfaces, faceted geom_rasters
g1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = dt_st_1_m , aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value))+
  scale_fill_viridis() + 
  coord_fixed()+
  facet_wrap(~variable)+
  guides(fill = guide_colourbar(barwidth = 1.5, barheight = 10))+
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "transparent"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = NA),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 20),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill=NA),
        legend.text = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 12),axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 22, hjust = 1))

# plot two is just the single delta raster
g2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = dt_diff_m , aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value))+
  scale_fill_viridis() + 
  coord_fixed()+
  ggtitle(bquote(Delta~layer)) +
  guides(fill = guide_colourbar(barwidth = 1.5, barheight = 10))+
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(size=20,hjust = 0.5,margin=margin(b = 1, unit = "pt")),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "transparent"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = NA),
        strip.text.x = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(hjust = 0, size = 12),axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 22, hjust = 1))

# now try to arrange the two plots/grobs in a single row
ggarrange(g1, g2, widths = c(2,1))
```

[image]

```
# try with patchwork package
(g1|g2)
```

[image]

```
# try with grid.arrange
gs <- list(g1,g2)
lay <- rbind(c(1,1,1,1,2,2),
             c(1,1,1,1,2,2))
grid.arrange(grobs=gs, layout_matrix = lay)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you read through all of the patchwork tutorials? I've had decent success with patchwork and some of the other options, like adding plot layout widths. See https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html. Not perfect, but a pretty phenomenal package.

Comment: FWIW, the patchwork code above worked for me when I made the plot window aspect ratio wider.

Comment: I'll experiment more with patchwork when I get a chance and report back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work using `cowplot::plot_grid`. I'm sure you can get the exact value to use in `rel_widths` by examining the heights of each plot using `gtable_show_layout()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706381/4083743) but `0.56` looks ok:

```
library(cowplot)
dd <- plot_grid(g1, g2, rel_widths = c(1, .56))
save_plot("test.png", dd, base_height = 9)
```

[image]

Comment: this was ok once i'd fiddled around with `rel_widths` a bit for my actual plots (so i needed different values) - it's obvious the inherent and relative sizing is different the more/less facets you have, so it's a case of trial and error?

Comment: Im sure there is a way to automate the process by extracting the heights separately and scaling but I haven't been able to do it yet, so trial and error for now

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the patchwork code and either making the plot window wider or giving the first plot more of the available plot width using:

```
library(patchwork)
g1 + g2 + plot_layout(widths = c(2,1))
```

[image]

Comment: (I don't like the higher title on the right, looking at fixing with theme...)

Comment: I suspect the title is coming from the fact one is a facet label and one is a title? But yes, aligning them is they next step. I'll definitely work on patchwork a bit more, though I have to say the right hand plot is bigger, even to the eye, just a tiny bit. Strange